# Transparent Child View Controller's View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a child view controller in a parent view controller and presenting it with the code below -

```
    self.addChildViewController(childVC)

    childVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)

    childVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]

    childVC.didMove(toParentViewController: baseVC)
```

The child view controller simply displays a 200 X 300 image view right in the middle. I want the child view controller to blur the parent view controller's view and display this opaque image view. However I can't seem to get it to show the underlying parent view controller's contents no matter what I do. I already tried the following in child view controller's viewDidLoad -

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

What am I missing here? Is there a better approach? The child view controller's purpose is to encapsulate the image preview logic by blurring the parent view controller's contents and display a UIImageView right in its view's center.

Comment: Did you try using the XCode Interface builder, I have achieved a similar feat there.

Comment: Try This : view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.8)

Comment: @MohammedZameer Preferably I would like to do this programmatically so that I can wrap the child view controller’s image preview functionality as a reusable framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ChildVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5). This code makes the child view appear semi transparent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `ViewController` as a `ChildViewController`.

Give segue to `ChildViewController` from `ParentViewController`.

set following `property`

- You have to select **Presentation** as `Over current context`
- You can also change the **Transition** based on your requirement

See following image

[image]

Comment: But how does it make the child view controller’s view a transparent see-through? In my case as you can see above the child view controller’s view completely covers the parent VC. So I want the child VC display a blurred background over the parent’s view and then render the image in the middle. So when it is all said and done on the screen, I want to see the image view and through the blurred background the parent view’s background image/color.

Comment: Also, if I follow this approach and do a self.present(....) from parent VC then the child VC is not really added as a parent is it?

Comment: after giving a segue you have to called `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sgOrderStatusPopup", sender: nil)` method from parent VC....so the childVC present on the parentVC

Comment: That's what I assumed but I don't want to use the storyboard/IB for this solution. The parent-child view controller approach works.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color of childViewController view as what you want and set its opacity 50% or 60% , whatever you want.

This will show parent view with blur effect.

Comment: The key is not to set the alpha on the child view controller's view. If this is set then that same alpha is set on all the subviews. So instead of doing this - `view.alpha = 0.5`, I did `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)` for it to work

Answer (score 0):

My original solution -

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

is working. My parent view controller's view is white with very sparse detail so I assumed that the parent view isn't visible, silly overlook on my part.